# Renegotiate SSL handshake

Tags: c, ssl, sip

Is it possible to do a renegotiation of the SSL handshake while the current SSL connection remains active. When the new handshake has succeeded the server should respond with a confirmation of the new handshake.

I've searched on SSL renegotiation but I couldn't find anything concrete. Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Comment: well you might be interested by the brand new wiki opened for openssl ( advertised today on openssl dev mailing list ) http://wiki.opensslfoundation.com/

Comment: Usually the sip tag refers to the Session Initiation Protocol. To what is the sip tag referring here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, renegotiation is part of TLS protocol. It can be both client- and server-initiated. Support for it depends on the implementation. Also, renegotiation made an [attack](http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2009/11/understanding_the_tls_renegoti.html) on TLS possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after a long search I finally found that renegotiation indeed makes it possible to re-challenge the chiper spec. I couldn't find anything clear in the docs or trough google but I accidentally found it in an article talking about TLS renegotiation attacks.

It is true that the TLS renegotiation attacks are fixed right?

Comment: @LeonKeijzer I'd say they are addressed in software, but not exactly "fixed in TLS". The reason is that the attack is not based on TLS flaw, but rather by the way certain software uses TLS.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation some time back, and we were using GoLang.
Renegotiate mode can be set by setting tlsCfg.Renegotiation to one of the following values:

1. RenegotiateNever
2. RenegotiateOnceAsClient
3. RenegotiateFreelyAsClient
   which are defined in https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/common.go

The following function can be used to set the request TLS Config.

```
func (r *request) SetRenegotiationMode(mode string) (IRequest, error) {

    modeMap := map[string]tls.RenegotiationSupport{
        "once":   tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
        "freely": tls.RenegotiateFreelyAsClient,
        "never":  tls.RenegotiateNever,
    }

    if val, ok := modeMap[mode]; ok {
        if r.tlsCfg == nil {
            r.tlsCfg = &tls.Config{}
        }
        r.tlsCfg.Renegotiation = val
    } else {
        //if anything other than the allowed values is passed, it'll thrown an error
        return nil, <DEFINE AN ERROR>
    }

    return r, nil
}
```